Can I fit a citation inside a phrase? (for a footnote)
My footnote as of now looks like this:

Whilst the term Rumi-ness has now become used by scholars to refer to the Anatolian Muslims identity, the Turkish Rûmîlik is still monopolized by people referring to the ideas of Mevlânâ Celâleddîn (known simply as Rûmî), one rare exception being “‘Rum’ Tabirini Yanlış Kulanıyoruz,” Esenler Belediyesi, February 28, 2019, accessed August 16, 2024, https://esenler.bel.tr/haberler/genel/rum-tabirini-yanlis-kullaniyoruz/; which nevertheless mentioned Rûmî himself.


Unfortunately my comment telling you that, yes, you can, was removed. But that's all the answer there is:
Yes, you can assimilate a citation into the surrounding text in a footnote. The CMOS gives several examples for this, all of which look similar to yours.

I cant seem to find examples similar to mine in the CMOS, could you tell me which section you looked at?

@VincentDesrosiers In section 14 there are a multitude of examples for footnotes and endnotes. Some contain run-in citations (sources given inside sentences of surrounding text). One example is in figure 14.6: "188 Speaking “as a citizen”: Quoted in Chicago Daily News, “Four Men Guilty,” Dec. 16, 1889." The first part ("Quoted in") is the "surrounding" sentence. The second ("Chicago Daily News, ...") is the citation. Obviously the citation is run-in in a note.
